# Linux Mint 21 vanessa Error ocurred in line: 1094

Tags: linux, error

```
whonix-installer-xfce: [NOTICE]: User agreed with the license.
whonix-installer-xfce: [NOTICE]: Detected system: Linux Mint 21 vanessa.
whonix-installer-xfce: [NOTICE]: Detected CPU architecture: x86_64.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: Error detected. Installer aborted.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: No panic. Nothing is broken. Just some rare condition has been hit.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: There is likely a solution for this problem.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: Try again. If this issue is transient (not happening again) it can be safely ignored.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: Please see Whonix News and Whonix User Help Forum.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: If not already reported, please report this bug!
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: Error ocurred in line: 1094.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: Please include the user log and the debug log in your bug report.
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: (For file locations where to find these logs, see above.)
whonix-installer-xfce: [ERROR]: Exit code: 2.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The message tells you what to do.

Did you check the "Whonix News and Whonix User Help Forum?", if this is not a known issue, did you report a bug?